# Install local private NPM dependency before prepublish

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a local private NPM dependency I reference in my application package.json:

"core-module": "file:///Users/myuser/Documents/projects/core_module"

When I run "npm install" on my application I want it to run a "npm install" on my local private dependencies (core-module).

It runs the prepublish script on install, but doesn't seem to run an install first which causes problems if I haven't ran a separate install on the local dependency first.

Any ideas how I can get my local private dependencies to run their own install when I run an install on the main application?

Answer (score 0):

On "scripts" section of package.json of your main application put:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "prepare": "npm explore core_module -- npm install"
}
```

When you execute "npm install" on your main application it before execute "npm install" on ./node_modules/core_module. More information [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/explore).

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario I wanted to install and check my private dependency before publishing, so what I did is simply run the `npm pack` command to create a tarball of my package. It will create a `pkgName-pkgVersion.tgz` tarball file which you can install separately wherever you want by using `npm install <tarball file path>` command before publishing the same.

For more clarification you can also refer the below link:
https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts